# Custom Admin Grid (alternatives?)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, admin, adminhtml, grid

I've planned to make a small module which allows the creation of a custom formula. Though I'm a little bit lost at the creation of the `admin section`. I managed to write a `system.xml` with `sections`, `groups` and `fields` but I have no idea how to give the user the option to add an element (like adding a new entry for the formula).
So I took a look at Grids and those seem to be the right way but also a bit too much for the little task I want to accomplish.

So what's the proper way to give the user the option to add an element with its own variables (e.g title="test", id=1, sort_order=1    etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

In the Tabs.php we create for the admin form, there is an addTab() function in which we pass the class’s path, of the `forms section` we want to add. What we can do is simply, put the class of our grid here.:-
example:-

```
$this->addTab('form_section', array(
     'label'     => Mage::helper('test')->__('Sample Grid'),
     'title'     => Mage::helper('test')->__('Sample Grid'),
     'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('fav/adminhtml_fav_edit_tab_grid')->toHtml(),
));`
```

see more:-http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-grid-serializer-admin-tabs-grid/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. So you would say a grid is the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

You can create tables (mini-grids, sort of) in the system configuration, using a custom frontend model that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract`

### Example

#### How it looks

[image: Example table]

#### system.xml

The field in `systeml.xml` for this example:

```
<shipping_costs translate="label">
    <label>Shipping Cost based on Price</label>
    <frontend_model>namespace_module/config_shippingCosts</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array</backend_model>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</shipping_costs>
```

#### Frontend model

Above you have defined a frontend model. You need to create this as a custom block

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Config_ShippingCosts 
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract
{
    public function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('from_price', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('From Price'),
            'style' => 'width:100px',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('cost', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Shipping Cost'),
            'style' => 'width:100px',
        ));

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Add');
    }
}
```

#### Usage

To use the configured data, you need to unserialize it, like this:

```
$shippingCosts = Mage::getStoreConfig('namespace_module/general/shipping_costs');
if ($shippingCosts) {
    $shippingCosts = unserialize($shippingCosts);
    if (is_array($shippingCosts)) {
        foreach($shippingCosts as $shippingCostsRow) {
            $fromPrice = $shippingCostsRow['from_price'];
            $cost = $shippingCostsRow['cost'];
            ...
        }
    } else {
        // handle unserializing errors here
    }
}
```

The example is taken from this tutorial: http://www.integer-net.com/2015/03/17/how-to-create-tables-in-magento-system-configuration/ where the code is explained in more detail.