# Custom component with ability to add/remove items (see attachment)

Tags: adminhtml, custom-options, custom

I was curious how I might be able to make a custom component like this in the Adminhtml area?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit broad as you don't say where you want to use such a component but I'll give it a shot:

- If it is for a system configuration value, please refer to this answer: [Custom Admin Grid (alternatives?)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72770/custom-admin-grid-alternatives/75289#75289)
- If it is in a custom form, you probably can reuse `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract` from above and render it yourself.
- If it is for a product attribute, have a look at the tier price block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Price_Tier` and see how it was implemented there, it's lots of custom code especially written for price attributes.